# Counting multiple values in a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to count multiple values (contained in a list per cell) on a groupBy object.

I have the following dataframe:

`|   | Record the respondent’s sex | 7. What do you use the phone for?           |
|---|-----------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
| 0 | Male                        | sending texts;calls;receiving sending texts |
| 1 | Female                      | sending texts;calls;WhatsApp;Facebook       |
| 2 | Male                        | sending texts;calls;receiving texts         |
| 3 | Female                      | sending texts;calls                         |`

I would like to count every value in column `7. What do you use the phone for?`, after grouping on `Record the respondent’s sex`.

I have no problem doing this when there is only one value per cell.

```py
grouped = df.groupby(['Record the respondent’s sex'], sort=True)

question_counts = grouped['2. Are you a teacher, caregiver, or young adult ?'].value_counts(normalize=False, sort=True)

question_data = [
      {'2. Are you a teacher, caregiver, or young adult ?': question, 'Record the respondent’s sex': group, 'count': count*100} for
      (group, question), count in dict(question_counts).items()]

df_question = pd.DataFrame(question_data)
```

Gives me a table which looks exactly like this:

`| 7. What do you use the phone for? | Record the respondent's sex | count |
|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------|-------|
| sending texts                     | Male                        | 2     |
| calls                             | Male                        | 2     |
| receiving texts                   | Male                        | 2     |
| sending texts                     | Female                      | 2     |
| calls                             | Female                      | 2     |
| WhatsApp                          | Female                      | 1     |
| Facebook                          | Female                      | 1     |`

If only I could get this working with multiple values!

`value_counts()` doesn't work on lists with multiple values, it throws an `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error. The question [Counting occurrence of values in a Panda series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825317/counting-occurrence-of-values-in-a-panda-series) shows how to deal with this in various ways, but I can't seem to get it to work on a GroupBy object.

Comment: Duplicating/exploding the multiple values into rows indeed seems like the simplest and fastest way to go about this (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows), altough the accepted answer below shows it can also be done without doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Initialize sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Record the respondent’s sex': ['Male', 'Female'] * 2, 
                   '7. What do you use the phone for?': [
                       "sending texts;calls;receiving sending texts",
                       "sending texts;calls;WhatsApp;Facebook",
                       "sending texts;calls;receiving texts",
                       "sending texts;calls"
                   ]})

# Split the values on ';' and separate into columns.  Melt the result.
df2 = pd.melt(
    pd.concat([df['Record the respondent’s sex'],
               df.loc[:, "7. What do you use the phone for?"].apply(
                   lambda series: series.split(';')).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1),
    id_vars='Record the respondent’s sex')[['Record the respondent’s sex', 'value']]

# Group on gender and rename columns.
result = df2.groupby('Record the respondent’s sex')['value'].value_counts().reset_index()
result.columns = ['Record the respondent’s sex', '7. What do you use the phone for?', 'count']

# Reorder columns.
>>> result[['7. What do you use the phone for?', 'Record the respondent’s sex', 'count']]
  7. What do you use the phone for? Record the respondent’s sex  count
0                             calls                      Female      2
1                     sending texts                      Female      2
2                          Facebook                      Female      1
3                          WhatsApp                      Female      1
4                             calls                        Male      2
5                     sending texts                        Male      2
6           receiving sending texts                        Male      1
7                   receiving texts                        Male      1
```

Comment: I had no idea about pd.melt(), and it seems to do the trick just great. Thanks!

Comment: In hindsight, going the route of just creating an extra row per multiple value (which is how MaxU noted this as duplicate) is easier and probably also faster.